# range() argument called tuple by my computer, but not by other compilers

Tags: python, tuples, typeerror

My heightmap generator function to initialize a matrix:

```
def initializeHeightMatrix(image_size):
    height_matrix = []
    for i in range(0,image_size):
        row = []
        for j in range(0, image_size):
            row.append(0)
        height_matrix.append(row)
    return height_matrix

matrix = initializeHeightMatrix(4)
print(matrix)
```

On a browser based compiler it worked but on my computer I get:

```
File "heightmapgenerator.py", line 31, in generateHeightMatrix
    for i in range(0,image_size):
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

So my ranges are now tuples?

Comment: image_size is a tuple. Thats what it could mean. Though you are calling it with (4). Can you debug it to line 31 and check the type of image_size?

Comment: As @Sheradil mentioned, how does your `image_size` variable assignment look like?

Comment: You have probably redefined the built-in function  `range`. What does `type(range)` report? Restarting the console/interpreter will most likely fix the problem.

Comment: @DYZ that was definitely it.

Answer (score 0):

Python has builtins and keywords. In my IDE or most frequently used text editor, keywords are colored differently than builtins, which are colored differently than program defined variable names. The word `range` is a builtin, as it is associated with the [builtin range class](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#func-range). While python will let you reassign builtins, it is not usually wise to do so unless you want to explicitly modify their functionality. To see all the builtins, simply try:

```
import builtins

print(dir(builtins))
```

Similarly, you see all the keyword (your compiler should raise a syntax error if you try and modify one of these) by doing the following:

```
import keyword

print(keyword.kwlist)
```

Somewhere in your code (possibly unknowingly), you probably did something like:

```
range = ('my', 'tuple')
```

To illustrate the issue, try this:

```
print(type(range)) # prints the builtin <class 'range'>

# then reassign range
range = ('my', 'tuple')

print(type(range)) # now prints <class 'tuple'>

# what is interesting is that tuples are iterable
# and you can use them in a for loop
for item in range:
    print(item)

# however, if you try and use your new tuple definition of range
# as you would use the builtin range class, you will get an error
try:
    for item in range(0, 100):
         print(item)
except TypeError:
    print("This doesn't work")

# this is analogous to writing something like
try:
    (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)(0, 100)
except TypeError:
    print("Bad programming alert!")
```